# Use Groupby of a python pandas dataframe without extending the column names

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate-functions, pandas-groupby

I would like to use the pandas groupby funktion but, without affecting the column names. E.g.:

My original dataframe:

```
df = DataFrame({'int_col' : [1,2,6,8,-1],\
                'float_col' : [0.1, 0.2,0.2,10.1,None], \
                'str_col' : ['a','b',None,'c','a']})
```

Result:

```
   float_col  int_col str_col
0        0.1        1       a
1        0.2        2       b
2        0.2        6    None
3       10.1        8       c
4        NaN       -1       a
```

Now I apply the groupby function:

```
f = {'int_col':['max'],'float_col':['sum']}
df_groupby = df.groupby('str_col', as_index=False,group_keys=False).agg(f)
```

This lead to the new dataframe:

```
  str_col int_col float_col
              max       sum
0       a       1       0.1
1       b       2       0.2
2       c       8      10.1
```

In the df_groupby dataframe, the column names gained a new level. I would like to suppress this

THX

Comment: Just do `df.groupby('str_col', as_index=False).agg({'int_col':'max','float_col':'sum'})`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `[]` in dictionary:

```
f = {'int_col':'max','float_col':'sum'}
df_groupby = df.groupby('str_col', as_index=False,group_keys=False).agg(f)
print (df_groupby)
  str_col  float_col  int_col
0       a        0.1        1
1       b        0.2        2
2       c       10.1        8
```

If want rename columns:

```
f = {'int_col':'max','float_col':'sum'}
d = {'float_col':'sum','int_col':'max'}
df_groupby = df.groupby('str_col', as_index=False,group_keys=False).agg(f).rename(columns=d)
print (df_groupby)
  str_col   sum  max
0       a   0.1    1
1       b   0.2    2
2       c  10.1    8
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to solve a similar issue by:

```
df_groupby.index = df_groupby.index.get_level_values(0)
df_groupby.columns = df_groupby.columns.map('||'.join)
```

This should flatten the df and merge the column names resulting in:

```
          str_col||  int_col||max  float_col||sum
0         a             1             0.1
1         b             2             0.2
2         c             8            10.1
```